# Laravel Storage File not downloading (File not found)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

in my laravel project i have uploads folder from where i am trying to download file.

**Folder Hierarchy:**

```
-Project
--Public
---Storage (created using php artisan storage:link)
----uploads
-----file.jpg ( i am trying to download)
```

Controller:

```
public function getdata(Request $request)
    {
        return Storage::download('/storage/uploads'.$image_name);
    //image name is file.jpg
      }
```

**Error:**

```
File not found at path: storage/uploads["file.jpg"]
```

Comment: how are you getting this `$image_name` variable?

Comment: $image_name = Files::select('file_name')->where('custom_code', $request->id)->first();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> File not found at path: storage/uploads["file.jpg"]

`[]` This shows you passing array in `path` and also `/` missing after **uploads**

Your path should be like below

```
storage/uploads/file.jpg
```

After above implementation your code would look like

```
Storage::download('/storage/uploads/'.$image_name);
```

Get Image from Database

```
$image_name = Files::select('file_name')->where('custom_code', $request->id)->first();
```

You can use `->first()` and image column accesible using `$image_name->file_name`

And In your way `$image_name[0]` access like that.

Comment: whyi it's returning array. my controller is:   $image_name= Files::where('custom_code','=',$request->id)->pluck('file_name');
        
        
      return  Storage::download('/storage/uploads/'.$image_name);

Comment: Updated answer..

Comment: File not found at path: storage/uploads/{"file_name":"file.jpg"}

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is something like this:

```
public function getdata(Request $request)
{
   return Storage::download("uploads/" . $image_name['file_name']);
}
```

reference:
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#downloading-files

Comment: File not found at path: uploads/{"file_name":"file.jpg"}

Comment: Wait, your $image_name is an array??

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-data/437121 i am trying to download it like this

Comment: What does 437121 stand for??

Comment: id/name of that file

Comment: File not found at path: storage/uploads/file.jpg

Comment: and are you sure you have that file.jpg on your storage/uploads directory??

Comment: yes it's there.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
return Storage::disk('public')->download('uploads/'. $image_name);
```

Comment: highlighted error: Undefined method 'download'.

Comment: are you sure about implement 'Storage' class ? 
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Comment: yes: use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage; is added

Answer (score 0):

after many tries , this works only in the browser . in postman , does not works .

```
return Storage::disk('public')->download('uploads/'. $image_name);
```